# Android - What is the approach to use to let the user choose from a small list of time-related options?

Tags: android, lists, material-design

I'm working on an app and I want to show the user how much he's paying for services he's got enabled.

I want the user to be able to choose to display the cost per day, week, month and year.

To let him switch between this cases, I'm using a spinner with a dropdown menu, but I'm not sure this is the right way to go.

Any advice would be appreciated.

This is how the menu looks right now:

[image: spinner dropdown menu]

Answer (score 1):

You're using the right component for sure.

The [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus) promote use of menus over dialogs, as they're less disruptive:

> In contrast to simple menus, simple dialogs can present additional
>   detail related to the options available for a list item or provide
>   navigational or orthogonal actions related to the primary task.
>   Although they can display the same content, simple menus are preferred
>   over simple dialogs because simple menus are less disruptive to the
>   user’s current context.

As for your concrete use of the menu, I can see a few things being wrong:

- The text should be left-aligned, not centered. Centering it makes it hard to read.
- The margins and padding are wrong. It not only looks messy, but the small height of each element makes it harder to tap the correct one.
- It's not at all clear that the element is actionable—it looks like a text label. Please at least add an arrow to the right, like this:

[image: Material drop-down menu]

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer. I will change the things you suggested